# Tracking all network access to server made by particular IP

Tags: ubuntu, logging, ufw, intrusion-detection, intrusion-prevention

Is there any way that I can track any network access (on any port) made to my server by a particular IP? I'm on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS and am using uncomplicated firewall.

Preferably, I'd be able to hook whatever the solution is into a script to email me whenever any activity occurs - but I'd be okay with results stored in a logfile instead.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [psad](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/). 
This place would be a nice start: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-psad-intrusion-detection-ubuntu-1604-lts-server

By default it can do all you're asking for any incoming ip address, but, it works via a LOG rule. If you match the IP you're looking for in the LOG rule, and just log traffic from it, psad will only work for this ip.

By default it bans the offending host too, but you can set it to trigger only mail and no ban actions.